# OAuth's client_secret in URL params

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

What's the reasoning behind `client_secret` being provided as URL parameter when exchanging `code` for `access_token`? URL params have their weakness, such as often being stored in logs. Considering the exchange is done via the `POST` method, why is the secret not passed in the payload instead?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the secret is passed in the header and different implementations of OAuth have either a sha hashing to secure the request. Is there a specific provider that you are referring to?

Comment: e.g. when using Google's implementation https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code the client_secret is passed as query parameter unless I overlooked something?

Comment: The link uses form post and contenttype : x-www-form... So this particular one does not use it in the querystring

Comment: I see `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the request